# Optimize a SQL query with 3 tables

Tags: sql, optimization

I have a SQL query which I ran for > 2 hours and had to stop it because it was taking long time. Would someone be able to give me pointers to optimize this query?

The Tab1 part has 300K records, but I assume 'contact' table is too big. I won't be able to add any indexes to optimize the performance bcoz this is one time thing.

```
SELECT Tab1.tradeType,
  Tab1.abuid,
  Tab1.JOBID,
  Tab1.uptime,
  Tab2.vendorName
FROM
  (SELECT tt.NAME AS tradeType ,
    abuid,
    jo.ID         AS JOBID,
    jo.UPDATETIME AS uptime
  FROM Job jo,
    vendortradetype tt
  WHERE updatetime >= sysdate -365
  AND tt.id         = jo.SC_VENDORTRADETYPE
  AND contactabuid IS NOT NULL
  ) Tab1
JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(name) AS vendorName, abid FROM contact GROUP BY abid
  ) Tab2
ON Tab1.abuid = Tab2.abid;
```

Comment: " I won't be able to add any indexes to optimize the performance bcoz this is one time thing" - then paraphrasing Bender "you're boned!"

Comment: What indexes do you have already?

Comment: Could you post the table schemas and the DMBS you're using, please?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it some situations that's true, but not convinced in this case.

Comment: @Charlieface : On the CONTACT table I have indices for 1) 'abid' and a few other fields( but not 'name') and 'name' and a few other fields - which I dont think will be  of much help in this case

Comment: Is both query (sub-query in FROM clause) takes much time when executed individually?

Comment: store the result of the first sub-query into a real table and let the second query use the real table then. This prevents, that the server has to hold everything in temporally memory. Then delete the table afterwards.

Comment: Please post the actual `CREATE TABLE` with indexes, please also share the query plan via http://pastetheplan.com

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest simplifying the query (as well as using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax):

```
SELECT tt.NAME AS tradeType, jo.abuid,
       jo.ID AS JOBID, jo.UPDATETIME AS uptime,
       (SELECT MAX(c.name)
        FROM contact c
        WHERE c.abid = jo.abuid
       ) as vendorName
FROM Job jo JOIN
     vendortradetype tt
     ON tt.id = jo.SC_VENDORTRADETYPE
WHERE updatetime >= sysdate - 365
      contactabuid IS NOT NULL;
```

In terms of performance, you want an index on `contact(abid, name)`.

By the way, with this formulation, you can check in the `contact` table is the issue simply by removing that column.

However, the query does not look particularly complicated.  I suspect that the issue is that the `JOIN` conditions are malformed (i.e. incomplete).  Otherwise, you might have other queries locking the tables.  That results in either waiting or copying the table (depending on the database), which can significantly slow things down.